# jQuery validation working just once problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a problem with validation

My validation script is working just once and after that, it doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function validateCurrency($currency) {
    var currencyFormat = /^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]+$/;
    return currencyFormat.test($currency);
  }

  $(document).on("change", "#price_meter", function() {
    if ($("#price_meter").val() === '' && !validateCurrency($("#price_meter").val())) {
      $("#price_meterError").html('لطفا قیمت متری ملک را به تومان وارد کنید.');
    } else {
      $("#price_meterError").html('');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<label for="price_meter">قیمت متری:</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="قیمت متری ملک" class="form-control divide" name="price_meter" id="price_meter">
<div id="price_meterError" class="text-danger mt-1 validate-error"></div>
```

Comment: what is the test condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use OR operator `||` instead of AND `&&` in your condition.

So your test will say if the current value is empty or is not match the pattern show the message else clear the message.

```
$(document).on("input", "#price_meter", function() {
    if ( $(this).val() === '' || !validateCurrency( $(this).val()) ) {
    __________________________^^
        $("#price_meterError").html('لطفا قیمت متری ملک را به تومان وارد کنید.');
    } else {
        $("#price_meterError").html('');
    }
});
```

**NOTE 1:** You could get the current value using `this` keyword like `$(this).val()`.

**NOTE 2:** I suggest the use of `input` event instead of `change` since it's more efficient when tracking the user inputs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function validateCurrency($currency) {
    var currencyFormat = /^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]+$/;
    return currencyFormat.test($currency);
  }

  $(document).on("input", "#price_meter", function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '' || !validateCurrency($(this).val())) {
      $("#price_meterError").html('لطفا قیمت متری ملک را به تومان وارد کنید.');
    } else {
      $("#price_meterError").html('');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<label for="price_meter">قیمت متری:</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="قیمت متری ملک" class="form-control divide" name="price_meter" id="price_meter">
<div id="price_meterError" class="text-danger mt-1 validate-error"></div>
```

Comment: when i change it to OR the #price_meterError doesn't disappear

Comment: $("#price_meterError").html('لطفا قیمت متری ملک را به تومان وارد کنید.');
this is the error message

Comment: Yes your message will display if the pattern you're trying is different ftom "111,111.1" or the field is empty

Comment: in this example if i enter correct value, the error message will show

Comment: What is the value you're trying ?

Comment: i want just currency value with comma and no more!

Comment: Show us the value please so we can see if the problem is in your pattern or elsewhere

Comment: So this the problem is coming from your pattern, you could mark one of the answers here since the main problem comes from the AND/OR operator, then post a new question for this specific problem to keep the things arranged... (I'll check it with you too)

Comment: sorry my english is not good. you mean i check the tick for AND/OR problem and make it green, then create a new post for pattern?

Comment: Yes that what I mean, to keep the two questions separated, in the new question you could describe more the pattern you want in other words the combination you want to allow just like you shows me in the other comment _`1,000 or 100,00 or 100,00,00 and ...`_

Comment: this is my new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334867/currency-validation-with-regex-code-in-javascript

Comment: Ok I'll check it

Comment: You've many downvotes, just remove the question and repost it with the snippet I have here and note that you've tried `/^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]+$/` with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your double ampersands (&&) to double pipes (||) in your conditional like this:

```
if ($("#price_meter").val() === '' || !validateCurrency($("#price_meter").val())){
```

Comment: when i change it to OR the #price_meterError doesn't disappear